# Pandas load from_records non-sparsely

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load a list of dictionaries into pandas as efficiently as possible.  Here is a minimal example for constructing my data, which I call below, `mylist`:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

random.seed(100)

mylist = []
for i in range(100):
    random_string_variable = "".join(random.sample("DINOSAUR", len("DINOSAUR")))
    random_string = "".join(random.sample("DINOSAUR", len("DINOSAUR")))
    for j in range(10):
        myrecord = {"i": i,
                    "identifier" : random_string,
                    f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_xx" : random.random(),
                    f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_yy" : random.random()*10,
                    f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_zz" : random.random()*100
                    }
        mylist.append(myrecord)

               
pprint(mylist[0:5])
[{'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_A_xx': 0.03694960304368877,
  'var_A_yy': 4.4615792434297585,
  'var_A_zz': 68.37385464983947},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_B_xx': 0.7476846773635049,
  'var_B_yy': 3.2014779786116643,
  'var_B_zz': 58.91595571819701},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_C_xx': 0.3502573960649995,
  'var_C_yy': 6.713087131908023,
  'var_C_zz': 74.36827046647622},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_D_xx': 0.23513409285324904,
  'var_D_yy': 3.894932754840866,
  'var_D_zz': 65.35552900764706},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_E_xx': 0.6660170004345193,
  'var_E_yy': 1.9094479278081555,
  'var_E_zz': 36.84983796653053}]
```

When I try to load this into pandas, it makes the data frame very non-sparse, with a lot of NaN repetition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist)
df
```

produces:

```
df
      i identifier  var_A_xx  var_A_yy   var_A_zz  var_B_xx  var_B_yy  ...  var_H_zz  var_I_xx  var_I_yy   var_I_zz  var_J_xx  var_J_yy   var_J_zz
0     0   NROUIDSA   0.03695  4.461579  68.373855       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
1     0   NROUIDSA       NaN       NaN        NaN  0.747685  3.201478  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
2     0   NROUIDSA       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
3     0   NROUIDSA       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
4     0   NROUIDSA       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
..   ..        ...       ...       ...        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...        ...       ...       ...        ...
995  99   SORIUDAN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
996  99   SORIUDAN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
997  99   SORIUDAN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...  63.72333       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
998  99   SORIUDAN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN  0.367797  4.162167  84.699542       NaN       NaN        NaN
999  99   SORIUDAN       NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN  0.634893  7.628154  75.903316

[1000 rows x 32 columns]
```

What I would like it to look like is:

```
               var_A_xx  var_A_yy   var_A_zz  var_B_xx  var_B_yy   var_B_zz  ...  var_I_xx  var_I_yy   var_I_zz  var_J_xx  var_J_yy   var_J_zz
i  identifier                                                                ...                                                              
0  NROUIDSA    0.036950  4.461579  68.373855  0.747685  3.201478  58.915956  ...  0.962999  7.332500  13.216899  0.847280  6.504308   8.552283
1  NURDASOI    0.814194  9.570388  21.239626  0.468727  6.180384  24.260818  ...  0.346681  9.865105  82.261586  0.221160  8.481875  92.645263
2  OARNDUIS    0.813418  1.103359   1.198749  0.646912  2.409214  76.037434  ...  0.404528  2.112085   8.461932  0.621124  5.372169  36.500880
3  DISORNAU    0.533450  1.094177  44.053734  0.804385  5.947438  28.360524  ...  0.121844  5.806337  85.657067  0.735207  4.011567  38.368097
4  SIONUDRA    0.672725  3.724022  58.280713  0.346717  7.432624  49.726532  ...  0.238869  0.769056  58.188641  0.415537  6.828866  38.802765
...                 ...       ...        ...       ...       ...        ...  ...       ...       ...        ...       ...       ...        ...
95 URIADNSO    0.231775  3.114448  65.241238  0.116461  4.330002  12.864624  ...  0.516712  5.589706  87.261427  0.572551  4.060943  80.102004
96 ISDONRAU    0.295684  8.406004  22.817404  0.160434  8.415922  47.288958  ...  0.050647  8.720049  44.407892  0.038166  5.027924  73.852513
97 OIAUSDNR    0.331393  9.480417  90.311381  0.985708  6.384429  55.459062  ...  0.947673  4.406426  68.098531  0.377523  5.258620  61.035638
98 DIONAURS    0.690593  4.316975   9.866558  0.822896  3.822044  68.863371  ...  0.994493  3.550660  22.769721  0.199187  7.254650  91.232969
99 SORIUDAN    0.960168  6.769579  49.488535  0.671168  1.577146  78.835216  ...  0.367797  4.162167  84.699542  0.634893  7.628154  75.903316

[100 rows x 30 columns]
```

You can see it is a 10x waste of memory to have the first representation.  Obviously, there are a variety of ways to get from A to B.  How can I tell pandas to /read in/ this list of records as non-sparse, as I assume this would be the most performant?  You can see extra records are inserted with NaN values.  I'm expecting 100 rows, where the index is given by `["i", "identifier"]` and 30 columns.

My preference is to do this at load time with the correct keywords and data load method, rather than relying after the fact on a pivot operations in pandas as they are comparatively slow.  I'm asking this question largely for performance, for example with much larger i and somewhat larger j.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist, index=["i", "identifier"])
df
```

Did not do the job.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist, index=["i", "identifier"]).unstack()
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Also fails.

If there do not exist arguments to ingest the list of dictionaries non-sparsely into a dataframe---this is the focus of my question---which of the `.agg`, `pivot_table`, `reshape`, `long_to_wide`, and `unstack` methods would be the fastest at getting from A to B for larger data sets?

Comment: *I'd ideally like to do this at load time* what is the type of data you receive? is it a dataframe or a list? Note that pandas start only when loaded as Dataframe, series etc...

Comment: Yes, I’m specifically asking about loading these records in pandas. The list provides a minimal repeatable example. Here’s where you can read more about minimal reproducible examples on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of MCVE/MRE , however I was not sure where do you want us to look at. At a pandas level when you have a dataframe created or iterating through the list and getting it pandas ready for example :) Its clear now

Comment: Thanks @anky.  I have updated my question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a number of ways to load the data as it is:

```
>>> df_idx = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist, index=['i', 'identifier'])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

Then we could group by columns or levels, and take the first non-NA value:

```
>>> df_idx.groupby(level=[0, 1]).first()
>>> df.groupby(['i', 'identifier']).first()
```

Those are both pretty much improved versions of `.agg()` as you don’t have to specify a lambda function.

Then with the same loading, we can try to reshape the data, with stack/unstack or melt/pivot

```
>>> df_idx.stack().unstack()
```

```
>>> pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(mylist), id_vars=['i', 'identifier']).dropna().pivot(index=['i', 'identifier'], columns='variable', values='value')
```

---

If that’s not satisfactory, there’s also reshaping before loading, which could be done through list comprehensions, and either `ChainMap` or dict comprehensions, or with numpy. This relies on the fact that there’s always 10 dictionaries with the same keys in a row, and chaining the same iterator the appropriate number of times with `zip()`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({k: v for d in tup for k, v in d.items()} for tup in zip(*[iter(mylist)] * 10))
>>> pd.DataFrame(ChainMap(*tup) for tup in zip(*[iter(mylist)] * 10))
```

```
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(mylist[n::10]) for n in range(10)], axis='columns')
>>> df.groupby(df.columns, axis='columns').first()
```

```
>>> reshaped = np.reshape(mylist, (100, 10))
>>> df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(reshaped[:,n]) for n in range(10)], axis='columns')
>>> df.groupby(df.columns, axis='columns').first()
```

I’ve measured with i=100 and j=10 as in your example and with i=1000 and j=100.

[image]

You can see which way you get the data into a dataframe does not matter: all `groupby` variants have the same results. As you suspect loading the data and then “fixing” it performs pretty bad. `pd.concat` does not work too well on 100x10 but scales better on the 1000x100 data, and what seems the best is pure-python `dict` iteration (maybe because it’ a comprehension and not a list? Not sure). The reshaping techniques, stack/unstack and melt/pivot, are always the worst.

Of course these results may change with different data sizes, and you probably know better what the right sizes to test are, based on your real data. Here’s the full script I used to run the tests so you can run some yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import ChainMap
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import timeit


def gen(imax, jmax):
    mylist = []
    l = ord('A')
    for i in range(imax):
        random_string = ''.join(np.random.permutation(list('DINOSAUR')))
        for j in range(jmax):
            var = f'var_{chr(l + (j // 26)) if j >= 26 else ""}{chr(l + (j % 26))}'
            mylist.append({
                'i': i,
                'identifier' : random_string,
                var + '_xx' : np.random.random(),
                var + '_yy' : np.random.random()*10,
                var + '_zz' : np.random.random()*100
            })
    return mylist

def load_rec_idx_groupby(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist, index=['i', 'identifier']).groupby(level=[0, 1]).first()

def load_rec_groupby(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist).groupby(['i', 'identifier']).first()

def load_dict_groupby(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylist).groupby(['i', 'identifier']).first()

def load_constr_groupby(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame(mylist).groupby(['i', 'identifier']).first()

def load_constr_stack(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame(mylist).set_index(['i', 'identifier']).stack().unstack()

def load_constr_melt_pivot(mylist, j):
    return pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(mylist), id_vars=['i', 'identifier']).dropna().pivot(index=['i', 'identifier'], columns='variable', values='value')

def load_zip_iter_dict(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame({k: v for d in tup for k, v in d.items()} for tup in zip(*[iter(mylist)] * j))

def load_zip_iter_chainmap(mylist, j):
    return pd.DataFrame(ChainMap(*tup) for tup in zip(*[iter(mylist)] * 10))

def load_concat_step(mylist, j):
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(mylist[n::10]).drop(columns=['i', 'identifier'] if n else []) for n in range(10)], axis='columns')

def load_concat_reshape(mylist, j):
    reshaped = np.reshape(mylist, (len(mylist) // j, j))
    return pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(reshaped[:,n]).drop(columns=['i', 'identifier'] if n else []) for n in range(j)], axis='columns')

def plot_results(df):
    mins = df.groupby(level=0).median().min(axis='columns')
    rel = df.unstack().T.div(mins)

    ax = rel.groupby(level=0).median().plot.barh()
    ax.set_xlabel('slowdown over fastest')
    ax.axvline(1, color='black', lw=1)
    ax.set_xticks([1, *ax.get_xticks()[1:]])
    ax.set_xticklabels([f'{n:.0f}×' for n in ax.get_xticks()])
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.4, bottom=.15)
    plt.show()


def run():
    candidates = {n: f for n, f in globals().items() if n.startswith('load_') and callable(f)}
    df = {}
    for tup in [(100, 10), (1000, 100)]:
        glob = {'mylist': gen(*tup), **candidates}
        dat = pd.DataFrame({name:
            timeit.Timer(f'{name}(mylist, {10})', globals=glob).repeat(5, int(100000 / np.multiply(*tup)))
            for name in candidates
        })

        print(dat)
        df['{}×{}'.format(*tup)] = dat

    df = pd.concat(df).rename(columns=lambda s: s.replace('load_', '').replace('_', ' '))
    print(df)
    plot_results(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is not from pandas, you can create the records according to what you want as a result. I edit your implementation as below,

```
import random
from string import ascii_lowercase

import pandas as pd

random.seed(100)

mylist = []
for i in range(100):
    random_string_variable = "".join(random.sample("DINOSAUR", len("DINOSAUR")))
    random_string = "".join(random.sample("DINOSAUR", len("DINOSAUR")))
    record = {
              "i": i,
              "identifier": random_string
    }
    for j in range(10):
        record[f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_xx"] = random.random()
        record[f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_yy"] = random.random() * 10,
        record[f"var_{ascii_lowercase[j].upper()}_zz"] = random.random() * 100
    mylist.append(record)

print(len(mylist))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mylist)
df
```

As it is about loading the records into Pandas, maybe it can be easier to process the list before passing into pandas such as

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import ChainMap

records = []
for k, v in groupby(mylist, key=lambda x: (x['i'], x['identifier'])):
    record = dict(ChainMap(*v))
    records.append(record)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot change how the data is generated. It is how it is.

Comment: I see, then you can use this, ```df = df.groupby(['i', 'identifier']).aggregate(lambda x: x.dropna())```

Comment: Thank you, that is not at load time, but an operation in pandas, with the data already having been loaded.

Comment: Thanks.  This ChainMap syntax is really slick and something I haven't seen before.  This code produced a lot of NaNs and the big shape still when I tried it in my real use case though, I need to test against this demo data again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with a pandas argument at load time, but you can use a comprehension to collapse your list of dicts into a single dict for each row

Data:

```
a = [
{'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_A_xx': 0.03694960304368877,
  'var_A_yy': 4.4615792434297585,
  'var_A_zz': 68.37385464983947},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_B_xx': 0.7476846773635049,
  'var_B_yy': 3.2014779786116643,
  'var_B_zz': 58.91595571819701},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_C_xx': 0.3502573960649995,
  'var_C_yy': 6.713087131908023,
  'var_C_zz': 74.36827046647622},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_D_xx': 0.23513409285324904,
  'var_D_yy': 3.894932754840866,
  'var_D_zz': 65.35552900764706},
 {'i': 0,
  'identifier': 'NROUIDSA',
  'var_E_xx': 0.6660170004345193,
  'var_E_yy': 1.9094479278081555,
  'var_E_zz': 36.84983796653053},
{'i': 1,
  'identifier': 'SORIUDAN',
  'var_A_xx': 0.03694960304368877,
  'var_A_yy': 4.4615792434297585,
  'var_A_zz': 68.37385464983947},
 {'i': 1,
  'identifier': 'SORIUDAN',
  'var_B_xx': 0.7476846773635049,
  'var_B_yy': 3.2014779786116643,
  'var_B_zz': 58.91595571819701},
 {'i': 1,
  'identifier': 'SORIUDAN',
  'var_C_xx': 0.3502573960649995,
  'var_C_yy': 6.713087131908023,
  'var_C_zz': 74.36827046647622},
 {'i': 1,
  'identifier': 'SORIUDAN',
  'var_D_xx': 0.23513409285324904,
  'var_D_yy': 3.894932754840866,
  'var_D_zz': 65.35552900764706},
 {'i': 1,
  'identifier': 'SORIUDAN',
  'var_E_xx': 0.6660170004345193,
  'var_E_yy': 1.9094479278081555,
  'var_E_zz': 36.84983796653053}
]
```

Cleaning the list of dicts:

```
# get list of keys--assumed here to be the identifier dict value
l_key = list(dict.fromkeys([l.get('identifier') for l in a]))
# a data dict we'll append the properly parsed dict to
data = list()
# iterate through original dict and append. 
for i in l_key: 
    l_data = [l for l in a if l.get('identifier') == i]
    data.append({k: v for d in l_data for k, v in d.items()})
```

adding data to the pandas df.

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I don't know that this would be faster than dealing with the data after you've loaded it into the DataFrame but it is another approach.

Comment: This is interesting, but since identifier can have duplicates, it's the tuple (l.get("i"), l.get('identifier')) that defines the record.  That modification also seems to render this quite slow.